# Way to know the width of the text in SKLabelNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

Is there a way to know the width of a "SKLabelNode" in Sprite Kit ?

OR I should use SKSpriteNode then use text inside it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because SKLabelNode is a subclass of SKNode, and SKNodes have a frame, you can query this and get the size of the SKLabelNode:

from the docs:

> The frame is the smallest rectangle that contains the node’s content,
>   taking into account the node’s xScale, yScale, and zRotation
>   properties. Not all nodes contain content of their own.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483026-frame

Here's some of the convenient properties, of a pretend `englishLabel`

```
englishLabel.frame.maxX
englishLabel.frame.midX
englishLabel.frame.minX    
englishLabel.frame.width
```